# Are phrases of the form 我[something]去 informal or slang (or just plain incorrect)?

Tags: grammar, usage

I've started using phrases with the structure 我[something]去 (wǒ [something] qù) with the meaning I'm going to do [something].

I've picked this up while in China because other people seem to say these things.  We don't have this sentence structure in English, and I'm not sure it's legitimate in Chinese.

Some examples I've used are:

- 我[跑步](http://dict.cn/%E8%B7%91%E6%AD%A5)去 (wǒ pǎobù qù) = I'm going to run. (Baidu [97,200](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E6%88%91%E8%B7%91%E6%AD%A5%E5%8E%BB) hits)
- 我[上厕所](http://dict.cn/%E4%B8%8A%E5%8E%95%E6%89%80)去 (wǒ shàng cèsuǒ qù) = I'm going to use the toilet (Baidu [506,000](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E6%88%91%E4%B8%8A%E5%8E%95%E6%89%80%E5%8E%BB) hits)
- 我[睡觉](http://dict.cn/%E7%9D%A1%E8%A7%89)去 (wǒ shuìjiào qù) = I'm going to sleep. (Baidu. [4,910,000](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E6%88%91%E7%9D%A1%E8%A7%89%E5%8E%BB) hits)
- 我[换衣服](http://dict.cn/%E6%8D%A2%E8%A1%A3%E6%9C%8D)去 (wǒ huàn yīfú qù) = I'm going to change clothes. (Baidu [1,460,000](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E6%88%91%E6%8D%A2%E8%A1%A3%E6%9C%8D%E5%8E%BB) hits)
- 我[礼拜](http://dict.cn/%E7%A4%BC%E6%8B%9C)去 (wǒ lǐbài qù) = I'm going to pray. (Baidu [240,000](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E6%88%91%E7%A4%BC%E6%8B%9C%E5%8E%BB) hits)

It seems common enough.  All of these examples could be rephrased 我去[something] and I think that would be legitimate.  But...

**Question**: Are phrases of the form 我[something]去 informal or slang (or just plain incorrect)?

Comment: see grammar e.g. ＂外国人实用汉语语法＂ or ＂实用现代汉语语法＂ [something] has to be a verb (+ object),（also explained at many online grammar sites) on complements of direction,趋向补语，来 and 去 are the only simple complements of direction 简单趋向补语，of course 我 can be replaced by any NP (also seems strange that none of the examples has a 了 in it),

Comment: search e.g. "directional complement", get many hits, e.g. https://www.chineseboost.com/grammar/basic-direction-complements-lai2-qu4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a correct usage of 我...去. It's usually used when asked "你干什么去？"

It would be like:

A: "你干什么去？"

B: "我跑步去"；“我上厕所去”；“我睡觉去”；“我换衣服去”；“我做礼拜去” （more clear than 我礼拜去）

When asked with "你（要）去干什么？"， one usually uses 我（要）去...

It would be like:

A: "你（要）去干什么？"

B: "我（要）去跑步"；“我（要）去上厕所”；“我（要）去睡觉”；“我（要）去换衣服”；“我（要）去做礼拜”

Those colloquial terms are commonly used in daily dialogues.